# split() vs rsplit() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, split, difference

I used `split()` and `rsplit()` as shown below:

```py
test = "1--2--3--4--5"

print(test.split("--")) # Here
print(test.rsplit("--")) # Here
```

Then, I got the same result as shown below:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] # split()
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] # rsplit()
```

So, what's the difference between `split()` and `rsplit()`?

Comment: There is no difference if you don't limit the number of splits.

Comment: Did you read the help description of both commands?

Answer (score 6):

- [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) can select the position in a string from **the front** to divide.
- [rsplit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) can select the position in a string from **the back** to divide.

```py
test = "1--2--3--4--5"

print(test.split("--", 2)) # Here
print(test.rsplit("--", 2)) # Here
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3--4--5'] # split()
['1--2--3', '4', '5'] # rsplit()
```

In addition, if `split()` and `rsplit()` have no arguments as shown below:

```py
test = "1 2  3   4    5"

print(test.split()) # No arguments
print(test.rsplit()) # No arguments
```

They can divide a string by one or more spaces as shown below:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] # split()
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] # rsplit()
```

And, only `str` type has `split()` and `rsplit()` as shown below:

```py
test = ["1 2 3 4 5"] # Doesn't have split()

print(test.split()) # Error
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

```py
test = True # Doesn't have rsplit()

print(test.rsplit()) # Error
```

> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'rsplit'